# Is it possible to combine these three join queries into one?

Tags: join, count

I would like to combine the counts of the stats by different hit_types into one query. Is that possible?

```
MariaDB [db]> select allurls.id, count(s1.id) from allurls inner join stats s1 on allurls.id = s1.allurl_id and s1.hit_type = 0 where s1.hit_date >= '2018-01-15'  group by allurls.id;
+-----+--------------+
| id  | count(s1.id) |
+-----+--------------+
| aaa |            1 |
| cnn |           16 |
+-----+--------------+

MariaDB [db]> select allurls.id, count(s1.id) from allurls inner join stats s1 on allurls.id = s1.allurl_id and s1.hit_type = 1 where s1.hit_date >= '2018-01-15'  group by allurls.id;
+-----+--------------+
| id  | count(s1.id) |
+-----+--------------+
| cnn |            1 |
+-----+--------------+

MariaDB [db]> select allurls.id, count(s1.id) from allurls inner join stats s1 on allurls.id = s1.allurl_id and s1.hit_type = 2 where s1.hit_date >= '2018-01-15'  group by allurls.id;
+-----+--------------+
| id  | count(s1.id) |
+-----+--------------+
| cnn |            4 |
+-----+--------------+
```

I tried to combine the first two but the numbers are all messed up and it eliminated the first result 'aaa'.

```
MariaDB [db]> select allurls.id, count(s1.id), count(s2.id) from allurls inner join stats s1 on allurls.id = s1.allurl_id and s1.hit_type = 0 inner join stats s2 on allurls.id = s2.allurl_id and s2.hit_type = 1 where s1.hit_date >= '2018-01-15' and s2.hit_date >= '2018-01-15' group by allurls.id;
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| id  | count(s1.id) | count(s2.id) |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| cnn |           16 |           16 |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

I expected to see

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| id  | count(s1.id) | count(s2.id) |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| aaa |            1 |            0 |
| cnn |           16 |            1 |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

Ultimately I want to also include `count(distinct(s4.source_id))`.

Here is a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tGP5SbC2AdGgeEwWTAgobf/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is anything that I miss here, but you can count conditionally like:

```
select allurls.id
    , count(case when s1.hit_type = 0 then 1 end) 
    , count(case when s1.hit_type = 1 then 1 end) 
    , count(case when s1.hit_type = 2 then 1 end) 
    , count(distinct s1.source_id)
from allurls 
join stats s1 
    on allurls.id = s1.allurl_id 
where s1.hit_date >= '2018-01-15' 
  and s1.hit_type between 0 and 2 
group by allurls.id;

 id     c1  c2  c3  c4
aaa     1   0   0   1
cnn     16  1   4   3
```

Some things to note:

I moved `hit_type` predicate to where, it does not make a logical difference, but I prefer to have only the relationship between tables in the join clause if possible.

distinct is not a function, `count(distinct(s1.source_id))` is confusing. Better use `count(distinct s1.source_id)`

Comment: Wow I didn't realize you can use `case` within `count`. So `count` only counts non-null values? I thought it counts all rows regardless of value.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`, where 1 being any value count number of rows (even rows where every column is null). `COUNT(x)`, where x being a variable count rows where x is not null.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, (at least partially):

```
SELECT allurls.id, COUNT(s1.id)
FROM allurls 
INNER JOIN stats s1 ON allurls.id = s1.allurl_id 
AND (s1.hit_type = 0 OR s1.hit_type = 1 OR s1.hit_type = 2) 
WHERE s1.hit_date >= '2018-01-15'  
GROUP by allurls.id;
```

Result:

```
 id  COUNT(s1.id)
aaa             1
cnn            21
```

The db-fiddle is available [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tGP5SbC2AdGgeEwWTAgobf/1) and the numbers appear correct in that they add up to the counts in the first 3 queries (individual - no `OR`). I'm giving a +1 to this question for providing a fiddle - as recommended [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) - if only all posters would do the same (sigh...)

I saw no s2, nor an s4, in the fiddle - maybe it needs to be expanded?

Comment: But how does that help? It just sums all counts. There are only 3 values: 0, 1, 2. Same as leaving `hit_type` out. How do I find the count of each individual `hit_type`? `s2` is in the 4th query. I just tried to join `stats` table twice. For `s4`, I tried (not shown) to join `stats` table 4 times, one time for each value (3 `hit_types` and `distinct(sources)`). If I learn the pattern for just 2 `hit_types`, then I can probably extrapolate to all 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a way with sub-queries (they fix everything), but I'm not sure this is the most efficient.

```
MariaDB [db]> SELECT allurls.id,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE allurl_id = allurls.id AND hit_type = 0 AND hit_date > '2018-01-15') AS c1,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE allurl_id = allurls.id AND hit_type = 1 AND hit_date > '2018-01-15') AS c2,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE allurl_id = allurls.id AND hit_type = 2 AND hit_date > '2018-01-15') AS c3,
  (SELECT count(DISTINCT( source_id )) FROM stats WHERE allurl_id = allurls.id AND hit_date > '2018-01-15') AS c4
FROM   allurls
HAVING c1 > 0; 

+-----+------+------+------+------+
| id  | c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
| aaa |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
| cnn |   16 |    1 |    4 |    3 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
```